Dokku Apps upstream port always disappearing
Anytime an app is rebuilt, the deployment fails and complains about the upstream app located in /home/dokku//nginx.conf.d/letsencrypt.conf
When i run nginx -t, i get the error below
nginx: [emerg] invalid port in upstream "127.0.0.1:" in /home/dokku/<app-name>/nginx.conf.d/letsencrypt.conf 
I will have to manually edit the file and insert the missing ports for about 5 apps and restart nignx before deployment can be successfully.
I tried checking online for the reason and a resolution, but no luck.
Has anyone encountered this issue before
I tried ensuring the upstream ports are in the letsencrypt file, checked the nginx and app logs file, also the log files for letencrypt but nothing
